# Excel formatting a number as 2.01E+12

Tags: excel

I have a large quantity of number strings that I have pasted into excel. I need to view each of the 12 digits in each number simultaneously. however the spread sheet has formatted it to, for example, 
2.01E + 12 and I can't seem to convert it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the cells
2. Select the "Home" tab
3. Select "Number" in the Number group dropdown
4. remove the excess decimals with the button shown in the image below

[image: Number Conversion]